# Iterating through list of lists to append values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to query a database so I create a list. I can re-use my list later so I append the queried values to my list.

```
item_details = [
    ['name', 'detail'],
    ['name', 'detail']
]

counter = 0

for item_detail in item_details:
    database_query = # Database query code
    item_details[counter].append(database_query.value)
    counter += 1
```

Is this efficient? Is this pythonic? Does what I'm doing make sense?

Comment: not sure why you are using a counter,  use enumerate

Comment: It may be useful to mention what kind of DB you are using.

Comment: Use `for counter, name in enumerate(item_details):` if you really need the counter.

Comment: In addition: It should be `counter += 1`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Can I get away without the use of the counter? I need to append the queried value to each list within item_details.

Giannis I'm using Google's Python NDB Datastore.

halex Thanks, was a typo on my part, corrected it.

Comment: @andrgl No need to use a counter. `name.append(database_query.value)` works as well

Comment: Generally not a good idea to query the DB in a for loop, if your list really is only 2 elements then not a big deal, but best to run fewer queries.

Comment: Typically if you want to associate a name with a value (or group of values, or object), you should use a dictionary.

Comment: `name` isn't a good name for a sublist which has both name and detail and is about to be name, detail, value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have [name, detail] in every sub-list and you are trying to add to every sub-list you'r database_querry? You shoudl try:

```
for index, name in enumerate(item_details):
    database_query = # Database query code
    item_details[index].append(database_query.value)
```

Because counters are usually not pythonic, unless they are collections.Couter :)
Hope I understood you'r question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some problems I can see.

Don't use manual counters. It is error prone and `enumerate()` does the job perfectly.

```
for name in item_details:
```

In this case `name` is already (a reference to) the inner list. So `name` isn't a really good variable name, here. I'm also not sure, why you want to

```
item_details[counter].append(database_query.value)
```

as this is the same as simply stating

```
name.append(database_query.value)
```

So all in all:

```
for i, item_detail in enumerate(item_details):
    database_query = # Database query code, hopefully needs i
    item_detail.append(database_query.value)
```

or even

```
for item_detail in item_details:
    database_query = # Database query code
    item_detail.append(database_query.value)
```

if the index is not needed.

In addition, you might consider not using a list of lists, but a list of dictionaries so that you can identify the individual items by name. Currently you identify them by their index position and that may cause confusion if you add more data.